# jquery remove element from array during foreach loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, foreach

I want to look for an item in an array and if i find it then i want to remove it and then break out of the loop. This is what i have but it only jumps back to the start of the second $.each

```
var tempArray = dataArray;

$.each(users, function(i, val) {
    var name = val.name;
// loop over each obj and match
$.each(tempArray, function(k, kval) {
   if(name === kval.username){
        tempArray.splice(k, 1);
    return;
   }
    });
});
```

How can i jump back to the start of the first loop so that it starts iterating over the nxt name? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning false in the second loop

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function `return false`. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: but what if you dont want to break the loop, but simply remove item[i] from the loop because it met a condition, and then continue on with your .each loop().  the documentation doesn't address that and I've seen some developers simply use return; within  a conditional statement for $(this) to be removed from the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Grep would grep only the values you want and discard the ones you don't want.

```
var persons = peopleArray;
$.each( users, function ( ii, user ) {
    persons = jQuery.grep( persons , function ( person ) {
        return ( person.userName !== user.name );
    } );
} );
```

Or javascript array fn {map, filter}:

```
var persons= [{name: "tom", age: 22 }, { name: "jerry", age: 23 }, { name: "XXX", age: 24 }]
, bads = [{ name: "XXX", pets: 9 }, { name: "YYY", pets: 6 }];

var badnames = bads.map(function(r){ return r.name });
alert( persons.filter( function(r) {
    return badnames.indexOf( r.name ) !== 0
} ).map( function ( r )    {
    return r.name
} ) );
```

EcmaScript 6
With shorthand (lambda '=>'), you can

```
var badnames = bads.map(r=>r.name );
alert( persons.filter( r=> badnames.indexOf( r.name ) !== 0 ).map(r=>r.name));
```

result "tom,jerry"